# difference between Hibernate template and JDBC template

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I want to know the difference between below configurations,how it works? and what is template design pattern.

```
 <bean  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" id="hibernateTemplate"></bean>

 <bean id="springJdbc" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"></bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check documentation:

- [JDBC doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)
- [Hibernate doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html)

Hibernate is for object serialization and JDBC is for database access.

Comment: as per the docs the hibernate template will convert hibernate exception to data access exception , it will give you auto commit transection facility or outside the transection, and it can also participate to the currentSession,and lazy loading will also work with the openSession.so it will provide you the automatic session  retriving and closing facility. rather we do try and catch block to the dao methods ,we can use hibernate template , the jdbc template is also doing something like that.. is there anything new about this?

Comment: what is hibernate callback exactly?

Comment: what if we use both in same application?